# DCGM Error: unable to establish a connection to the specified host: localhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, gpu, nvidia

I'm using aws and my environment is:

- AMI : Deep Learning AMI GPU CUDA 11.4.1 (Ubuntu 18.04) 20211204
- g4dn.xlarge instance (T4)

and install DCGM refer to this link https://developer.nvidia.com/dcgm
(The version was modified from ubuntu20 to 18 and installed)

after install DCGM, When I enter that statement, I get the following error

> Error: unable to establish a connection to the specified host: localhost
> Error: Unable to connect to host engine. Host engine connection invalid/disconnected.

Comment: what is the exact output when you do `sudo systemctl --now enable nvidia-dcgm` as indicated [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/dcgm/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#post-install).

Comment: @Robert Crovella
you Genius!! thank you so much!